# Comparing LocalDate with date part of LocalDateTime in apache ignite

Tags: date, datetime, h2, ignite

I have a certain records in ignite cache and I want to retrieve all records for current day. For this I need to compare LocalDateTime type field of cached object with Localdate object i.e LocalDate.now(). How do I write a query to do this. In oracle TODATE(date, format) does the same thing but this function is not present in H2.
cached field datetime: 2016-08-30T05:31
date instance :  2016-08-30
SQL will be like 
String sql = "select * from cacheName where date='convert(datetime) to date'";
Is it possible in H2 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use custom SQL functions for this: https://ignite.apache.org/releases/mobile/org/apache/ignite/cache/query/annotations/QuerySqlFunction.html

For example, if your value class looks like this:

```
public class MyValue {
    @QuerySqlField
    private LocalDateTime time;

    public MyValue(LocalDateTime time) {
        this.time = time;
    }
}
```

You can create a function like this:

```
public static class MyFunctions {
    @QuerySqlFunction
    public static String toDate(LocalDateTime time) {
        return time.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE);
    }
}
```

And provide it in the configuration like this:

```
cacheCfg.setSqlFunctionClasses(MyFunctions.class);
```

The query will look like this:

```
select * from MyValue where toDate(time) = '2016-08-30'
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for reply. Is it possible to avoid '@QuerySqlFunction' annotation and provide this using xml like QueryEntity for '@QuerySqlField '?

Comment: No, this is not possible. But why is this an issue for you?

Comment: I sorted it out, not a big issue, we just wanted to have ignite dependencies in one place and this model object was out side the module. but moved item to get it working.
Thanks for replying again.